# How to pass the parameter in the nested query in graphql?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

```
  {
        player(id : "Pogba") {
            name,
            kit {
                shirtSize,
                bootSize
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code work fine but i need

```
{
    player(id : "Pogba") {
        name,
        kit (name:name){
            shirtSize,
            bootSize
        }
    }
}
```

but i need to pass the player query response to the kit query with nested format. Is it possible to achieve this? Appreciate any help.

Comment: If the player object you return inside your `player` field's resolver includes an `id`, this will be accessible under the first parameter passed to the `kit` field resolver.

Comment: i think you say about id pass to kit query
  {
        player(id : "Pogba") {
            name,
            kit (_id:id){
                shirtSize,
                bootSize
            }
        }
    }
Above code work fine but i need

{
    player(id : "Pogba") {
        name,
        kit (name:name){
            shirtSize,
            bootSize
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get player query response as the first argument in kit field level resolver.

```
type Kit {
  shirtSize: String
  bootSize: String
}

type Player {
  name: Stirng
  kit: Kit 
}
```

```js
const PlayerResolver = {
  Player: {
    kit: {
      // language=GraphQL
      fragment: `fragment PlayerFragment on Player { name }`,
      resolve: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
         // you can access the parent object to fetch its parent data;
         console.log(parent.name);
      }
    }
  }
};

export default PlayerResolver;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to define on the type that the field can take a parameter

```
type Player {
  name
  kit (name: String): Name
}
```

Comment: and where can I access the `name` parameter in my resolver?  Can I see this parameter in the `Player` resolver?